What this task is and is not about? Birkhoff and interesting property of isotone transformation
Citing:

Show that any isotone transformation $P \rightarrow P_1$ of one poset $P$ onto another poset $P_1$ carries connected components of the graph of $P$ into connected components of the graph of $P_1$

First ambiguity lies in my absence of knowledge what exactly "transformation" means in such context. My assumption -- it's just isotone (order-preserving) function, where $P_1$ has the same set of elements as $P$. Or where image of $P$ should contain the same number of elements as $P$ itself. That's it.
If this assumption is false, then I don't know whether $P_1$ should tell me any useful information or not. Googling hasn't help much,  nor has "parsing" through Birkhoff's book.
And what exactly "carrying components of graph of $P$ into components of graph of $P_1$" (assuming "component" is the same thing as "connected component")?
Bijection between components? Or it is allowed to "merge" several vertices of one component of graph $P$ into one element of graph $P_1$
Just for clarification, by "connected component" I mean a maximal connected subposet $S$, where "connected" is true iff $\forall a, b \in S$ there is finite sequence $a = c_1, c_2, ..., c_n = b, c_i \in S$, such that for any $i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$, the following holds: $c_i \leq c_{i+1}$ or $c_i \geq c_{i+1}$
Additionally very simple isotone function troubles me the most.
Assume we have any poset $P$ with $n$ components, $n \geq 2$. Define isotone function as $\forall x \in P: f(x) = c \in P_1$, where $c$ is some fixed element. Easy to see it's indeed isotone with order $\leq$ (reflexivity, antisymmetry, transitivity).
And in such case $n$ components merge into one single element which, I assume, contradicts with task condition.
Sorry for such a long text. I hope my troubles are going to be well understood despite problems with English

By "isotone transformation" Birkhoff just means an isotone map. There is no indication that $P_1$ has the same underlying set as $P$, or even the same number of elements — it is just another poset.

Or it is allowed to "merge" several vertices of one component of graph $P$ into one element of graph $P_1$

Yes, multiple connected components in the source may be taken to the same connected component in the target as you noted. The exercise is not asking you to prove something false: all it is saying is that an isotone map cannot "separate" a connected component of the source into multiple connected components of the target. Formally, for every connected subposet $S \subseteq P$, $f(S)$ is connected in $P_1$ (thus contained in a maximal connected subposet of $P_1$).

Thank you very much! It was much easier than I expected. Have a good day and happy holidays!
